# Color coded background of a 2d Plot and a density plot

Tags: matlab, plot, density-plot

I want to make a plot like this one:

[image]

Assume I have this 2d plot:

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
plot(x,exp(-(x-5).^2))
```

I want to color the background according to the value of the x axis. So that I get the plot shown above.
Now assume I have a matrix which its entries are within the limits of the x axis of my 2d plot.

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = 0:0.1:10;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
dis = exp(-(X-5).^2-(Y-5).^2);
imagesc(x,y,dis)
```

How can I use the same color code as the 2d plot in the density plot?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to plot:

[image: background colorcode]

this is the code for that, but if you state more clearly what is missing in this example, I will try to adjust it:

```
x = 0:0.01:10;
dis = exp(-(x-5).^2);
colormap jet
imagesc(x,[min(dis) max(dis)],-x)
axis xy
hold on
plot(x,dis,'k')
ylim([min(dis) max(dis)])
hold off
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to have a gradually increasing gradient ("_color the background according to the value of the x axis_"), not a symmetrical one . Note: You are not using `y` after defining it ...

Comment: @Hoki Thanks for the comment (I hope you right), I have edited the answer